I am getting Ivy incompatibility error through out the project but while building the appln it is fine
'ChartsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
charts.d.ts(33, 49): This likely means that the library (ng2-charts) which declares ChartsModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
I have updated my node js for other project.
